# Get class from other project, with a twist?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

So, i've got a few LibGDX games that i'm working on. (Java w/ Eclipse).

I've got a few classes that Extend LibGDX classes.

For example:
Project A:

```
public class GraphicSprite extends Sprite {
}
```

The problem is, i've got a few projects using the same class. So when I change it in one project, I have to update it for all of them.

I read that I can use a Java Build Path of another project.
Would the resources project have to be a LibGDX Project? Because the classes use LibGDX features.

If the resources project has to be a LibGDX project, and i'm importing that into my other LibGDX project, would it double the project size?

Comment: I would advise you to carefully gather such classes, if you have any other,  into an android library project that depends on LibGDX with exporting on, and then all your projects should depend on this library project in turn. Peer dependency is usually ugly and cumbersome.

Comment: Edit: Ok, so Project A is a LibGDX Project. I want to have a Project B for GraphicSprite class, which extends Sprite.  Would Project B need to be a LibGDX Project as well? And would including Project B in A increase the project size (because it includes LibGDX)?

Comment: i) Yes Project B will need to be a LibGDX project as well. ii) The project size will most likely not double, if they have the same classpath or they reference to the same jar files. tip for i) I believe LibGDX is very free, mit? apache?, in terms of license. If their sprite class does not have tonnes of dependencies you can skin it off.

Answer (score 1):

One solution (that I'd highly recommend) is to not change the classes that you are extending from, and simply make a unique extension of the classes you want from the lib for each project. The value to doing this is that you keep the library stable and ignorant of what it is being used for while the extended project classes can alter and override the original behaviour as necessary without making changes that effect other projects.

Comment: I am extending them.  I want to have the resource classes INSIDE of a resoucred project. So that I can edit them easily.

Comment: I guess the question would be why would you want to edit the resource classes as oppose to just overriding them? For that, you could just make a copy of the resource classes into each of the project directories, but I don't know what your intention with the resources is.

Comment: Edit: Ok, so Project A is a LibGDX Project. I want to have a Project B for GraphicSprite class, which extends Sprite. Would Project B need to be a LibGDX Project as well? And would including Project B in A increase the project size (because it includes LibGDX)?

Comment: You should be able to add project A as a project dependency to project b. In eclipse, I belive you can right click on project B, go into the project's settings and add project A as a dependency. That will allow project B to extend Sprite, assuming Sprite is in Project A